# GWT Java - CellTable - ButtonCell - how to make it respond to a click

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I have the following ButtonCell. How do I make it respond to a click please (e.g., addClickHandler)? I have tried a number of ways I have found yet none work. None of the Window.alert return a response.

```
        ButtonCell selectButton = new ButtonCell();
        Column <HikingMeals,String> update = new Column <HikingMeals,String>(selectButton){
            @Override
            public String getValue(HikingMeals selectButton) 
            {
                return "Select";
            }
            public void execute(HikingMeals selectButton) {
                // EDIT CODE
                Window.alert("Pressed");
             }
            //@Override
            public void update(int index, HikingMeals object, String value) {
                // The user clicked on the button for the passed auction.
                Window.alert("Pressed2");
            }
        };
        table.addColumn(update, "Select");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a `FieldUpdater` on the `update` column:

```
update.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<HikingMeals, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, HikingMeals object, String value) {
        Window.alert("Pressed");
    }
});
```